# String Incorrectly Converted to Hex in java

Tags: java, string, hex

My java code for a reason I cannot figure out converts a string to hex when I only want a particular character converted to hex based upon criteria.  Please see the below code and output.

```
for (int n = 0; n < line.length(); ++n) {
    char aChar = line.charAt(n);
    if (Character.isLetter(aChar) || Character.isDigit(aChar)
            || aChar == '_' || aChar == '-' || aChar == '.'
            || aChar == '*') {
        encoded += +aChar;
    } else if (aChar == ' ') {
        encoded += +'+';
    } else {
        String hexValue = Integer.toHexString(aChar);
        encoded += '%' + hexValue;
    }
}

System.out.println("The encoded string is: " + encoded);

System.out.println("Length in chars is: " + encoded.length());
```

Output:

> Enter a line of text to be URL encoded
>
> aaddcc
>
> The string read is: aaddcc
>
> Length in chars is: 6
>
> The encoded string is: 97971001009999
>
> Length in chars is: 14

The above code is the meat of it

Comment: It is due to the `+` sign, which cause an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, then `int` is converted to decimal number for String concat.

Comment: If this is not an exercise, use this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Nhahtdh explained your errors. To solved them change `encoded += +aChar;` to `encoded += aChar;` and `encoded += +'+';` to `encoded += '+';`. Otherwise `+` will cast `char` to `int`, which return position of `char` in Unicode table.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the comments, the reason this is failing is because of a small error in how you're trying to do String concatenation. The correct way to join two `String` objects is like the following examples:

```
"Hello " + "World"; //Adding two String constants
"1st String" + stringVariable; //Appending a String variable to a String constant
firstString + secondString; //Concatenating two String variables
"Favourite letter: " + 'a'; //Join a String and a char
"Age: " + 21; //Join a String and an int - result is "Age: 21"
```

The `+=` that you're using is a shortcut, but `x += y` essentially expands out to `x = x + y`. Where you write `encoded += + '+'` this expands to `encoded = encoded + + '+'`. This doesn't make sense for `char`-type variables, but if the `char` is converted to an `int`, then the compiler can interpret the expression as `encoded + (+43)`, where 43 is the result of casting the `'+'` character to an `int` (ie. `(int)'+'`), and `(+43)` is an unnecessarily precise way of stating that `43` is positive.

The following two lines are equivalent

```
encoded += +'+';
encoded += 43;
```

Likewise when you use `aChar`, although the cast to an `int` will result in different integers being added depending on the current character.